# Сгуппировать несколько аннотаций в одну

Tags: java, hibernate, рефакторинг, аннотации

Заметил у себя в проекте часто повторяющиеся аннотации над одним полем в разных сущностях, можно ли их как то заменить на свою собственную, с сохранением сообщений и лимитов.

**Из такого:**

```
@NotBlank(message = USERNAME_ERROR_BLANK)
@Size(message = USERNAME_ERROR_LENGTH_SIZE,
    min = USERNAME_LENGTH_MIN,
    max = USERNAME_LENGTH_MAX)
@Nullable
@Attributes(required = true,
    pattern = PATTERN_STRING,
    minLength = USERNAME_LENGTH_MIN,
    maxLength = USERNAME_LENGTH_MAX)
private String username;
```

**Получить такое:**

```
@MyUsernameAnnotation
private String username;
```

Знаю что можно написать свой валидатор, но мне не нужно особенное поведение, хотелось бы просто сгруппировати их.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Валидатор Hibernate поддерживает составные аннотации валидации.

Подробнее: [Hibernate Validator - Constraint composition || docs.jboss.org/hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=5.4#section-constraint-composition)

В соответствии с документацией, `@MyUsernameAnnotation` может выглядеть следующим образом:

```java
@NotBlank(message = USERNAME_ERROR_BLANK)
@Size(message = USERNAME_ERROR_LENGTH_SIZE,
        min = USERNAME_LENGTH_MIN,
        max = USERNAME_LENGTH_MAX)
@Nullable
@Attributes(required = true,
        pattern = PATTERN_STRING,
        minLength = USERNAME_LENGTH_MIN,
        maxLength = USERNAME_LENGTH_MAX)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = { })
public @interface MyUsernameAnnotation {
}
```

И объявление поля:

```java
@MyUsernameAnnotation
private String username;
```

Comment: Не работает, похоже надо всю начинку добавлять также в класс общей аннотации.